# Warning "Method definition not found" in Objective-C. Call Method from Category file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-category

I have created some method in category file. I just want to reuse those methods in my view controllers. So I have imported that category file in  view controllers and declared the method in header file also.
calling it like this:

Category class:

```
@interface UIViewController (headerView)
-(UILabel *)someMethod;

@implementation UIViewController (headerView)
-(UILabel *)someMethod{
}
```

HomeViewController:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController
-(UILabel *)someMethod;

@implementation HomeViewController
[self someMethod];
```

I am getting warning message in this line:

```
@implementation HomeViewController
```

It's working. But I want to clear this warning. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "reuse those methods in my view controllers"?  Categories add methods to existing classes.  The only issue with calling the methods is making their definition known to clang.  It sounds like you missed a step.  Perhaps post the category interface and show how you import it.

Comment: what warning message you getting ?

Comment: Show your all code that how you create category and how you import that in your `viewcontroller` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you category in view controller do it something like that

*Your category*

```
@interface UIViewController (ExtendedMethods)
- (void)someMethod;
@end

@implementation UIViewController (ExtendedMethods)
- (void)someMethod {
  NSLog(@"Some method");
}
@end
```

*MyViewController.m*

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+ExtendedMethods.h"

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self someMethod];
}
@end
```

Comment: yes. Exactly I have did like this. But getting warning message. How to clear that?

Comment: Are you getting any warning over this line ? - implementation MyViewController

Comment: Nope, I haven't got any warnings. Are you sure you have someMethod in category Header file? Maybe you misspell it?

Comment: Also make sure that you import #import "UIViewController+ExtendedMethods.h" in file where are you trying to use these methods from category

Comment: ya. I have declared someMethod in MyViewController header file again. Here the mistake. Thanks mate. Thank for your help!